# Find single element from a non-empty array of integers, every element appears twice except for one

Tags: python

I need to find single element from a non-empty array of integers (every element appears twice except for one, I have to find the one).

My code is not giving desired result for sample test case (2,2,1). It should ideally return 1 as result but it is returning Null instead. Can you help me understand the issue with it.

```
def singleNumber(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(1,len(nums)-1):
        if i==len(nums)-1:
            if nums[i]!=nums[i-1]:
                return nums[i]
        if nums[i]!=nums[i+1] and nums[i]!=nums[i-1]:
            return nums[i]
```

Comment: step debuggers exist for a reason ...

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison logic is faulty.  None of your `if` statements will find the odd value.  As a result, your function returns the default value of `None`.

In particular, this fails to find the case when the first element is the odd one.  You do try to check for the last element.

I suggest that you employ some basic debugging.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.   In this case:

```
for i in range(1,len(nums)-1):
    print(i, nums[i-1:i+1])
    if i==len(nums)-1:
        print("End of list check")
        if nums[i]!=nums[i-1]:
            return nums[i] 

    print("Middle of list check")
    if nums[i]!=nums[i+1] and nums[i]!=nums[i-1]: 
        return nums[i]
```

---

Note that there is an easier, canonical way to do this:  Simply iterate through the list without sorting.  XOR all of the elements together.  The paired elements will cancel each other, leaving the one odd element.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the XOR operator that [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) was mentioning. If you check the result of

```
print(2^2^1^1^4^4^7)
```

It prints 7. So if you chain the entire array together with the XOR operator (^), the final result will be the number that is unpaired.

I just spent some time going over it and did this:

```
test_list = [2,2,1,3,3,4,6,7,7,6,0,0,4,1,16,9,9]

unpaired_number = test_list[0]
for element in range(1, len(test_list)):
    unpaired_number = unpaired_number^(test_list[element])

print(unpaired_number)
```

The above block gives 16 if you run it.

Previous solution:

```
from collections import Counter

test_dict = dict(Counter([2,2,1,3,3,4,6,7,7,6,0,0,4]))

for element in test_dict:
    print(f"Number of appearances: {test_dict[element]} for the element {element}.")
    if (test_dict[element]==1):
        print(f"Unpaired element: {test_dict[element]}")
```

Here is my code.

I tried avoiding sort based on the comments of some previous answers. The XOR method mentioned by [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) is a bit over my head.

The code uses the Counter method from collections to determine the total number of times a given element is repeated and if there is a single element that only appears once, it will tell you which element that is. I modified your set a bit so there were more numbers to run through.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in the index. Arrays and lists are zero indexed, and, since you sorted, one should be first in your array. That means that instead of using:

for i in range(1,len(nums)-1):

you should use

for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):

That way it won't skip the 1